# Ubuntu 16.04 does not find "Singapore" in Time & Date, and the time is wrong

Tags: 16.04, language-support, time, timezone

I have a brand new Dell Precision Tower 5000 Series (5810) that just came with Ubuntu 14.04 pre-installed. Instead of upgrading to 16.04, I made a fresh installation (no dual boots).

I was not able to boot from USB, but luckily I had a DVD with 16.04. Installation using the DVD went with no problem.

During the installation, I was able to select Singapore as my location. However, once I opened Ubuntu for the first time, I noticed the following:

1. It is showing a totally incorrect time, around 7h ahead.
2. It claims it is Jakarta time (which is not) when I explicitly selected Singapore during the installation.
3. It shows weekday and month in Indonesian, even when everything is set to English.
4. It does not find anymore "Singapore" in the Time & Date settings, even when I was able to select it during installation.

Please check the images attached, at the time of writing this it's 9:20AM, not 4:20PM.

Many thanks!

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

Comment: my guess is BIOS time is set to local - where it should be set to UST which is the same everywhere in the world.  my guess is BIOS time is probably "7hr ahead" of universal.standard.time  (UST ~= GMT with no daylight savings)

Comment: How can I change that?

Comment: Is it a reported bug the fact that Singapore doesn't appear among in Date & Time in 16.04?

Answer (score 1):

Start a Terminal and use the following command:

```
timedatectl set-timezone Asia/Singapore
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is a bug since I see no choice for Singapore on any of my Ubuntu 16.04 machines.  16.04 has been out for a long time and Singapore is a major Republic.  I'd be surprised if there isn't a bug report already issued on this.

As a work around I suppose you'll need to select another location that's in the same time zone as you are.  Phnom Penh perhaps?

Comment: for the moment, I just introduced it manually... I don't recall having this problem before, even with 16.04

Answer (score 0):

In xUbuntu 16.04 at least presents time zome 'Asia/Singapore'. But you can still use any time zone with GMT+8 like Malaysia's or China's time zones.

Comment: using a different timezone with the same GMT/UTC value isn't a good idea because different zones may follow different rules (DST, date/time change...). For example China time is [very different from Singapore time in the past](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singapore_Standard_Time#Timeline) so [dealing with history times will be difficult](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6841479/995714). Another example: [What's the difference between GMT+01:00 Amsterdam and GMT+01:00 Brussels?](https://superuser.com/q/1188122/241386)

Answer (score 0):

For time, go to Time & Date -> clock -> Time in auto-detected location work for me (I am in Singapore)

For weekday and month in Indonesian, go to Language Support -> Regional Format then change to English and reboot.

Answer (score 0):

I logged an issue directly related to this; great if someone else who hits this can confirm it, so the bug gets onto the radar:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1826832